# Dereferencing pointer to container class member

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, dereference, scoping

I have the following problem I want to be solved. I started out with a large class P, which I wanted to split up. Therefore a part of the functionality was moved to a new class Q. However, I do not seem to be able to make these two communicate properly. To make this a bit more visual, I made this toy example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Q {
public:
    int* x_ptr;

    Q(){ } // Is there any way to not have to write default constructors?

    Q(int* x_ptr){
        x_ptr = x_ptr;
    }

    void say_x(){
        std::cout << *x_ptr << std::endl;
    }

    void change_x(){
        *x_ptr += 1;
    }
};

class P {
public:
    Q q;
    int x;

    P(int x){
        x = x;
        q = Q(&x);
    }
};

int main(){
    P my_p = P(10);
    my_p.q.say_x();
    my_p.q.change_x();
    std::cout << my_p.x << std::endl;
}
```

I want the class Q to be responsible for changing P.x. To do this, I thought that passing a reference to P.x to Q when it's created would work. However, this results in a segmentation fault. *Is there a way to make Q able to access and modify x?* The reason for this is that I eventually want to have a number of classes Q1, Q2 etc, which are all responsible for different operations on P.x, where P.x will be a more complicated data type than a simple int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems arise from the fact that your are using the same variable names for both function arguments and class members. Although this is allowed, it is (IMHO), *very* bad practice. If you want to keep the names, then you will need to add an explicit `this->` in the functions where you need to distinguish between the two, otherwise your argument names will ['shadow'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the class members.

So, your `Q` constructor, keeping the name-clashes, would need to be:

```cpp
    Q(int* x_ptr) {
        this->x_ptr = x_ptr;
    }
```

and your `P` constructor would be:

```cpp
    P(int x) {
        this->x = x;
        q = Q(&(this->x));
    }
```

However, with simple name-changes to the arguments, this is much clearer:

```cpp
    Q(int* arg_x_ptr) {
        x_ptr = arg_x_ptr;
    }
//...
    P(int arg_x) {
        x = arg_x;
        q = Q(&x);
    }
```

As it stands, in your code, the line `q = Q(&x);` in the `P` constructor passes the address of the temporary object given as the argument, which causes a memory error (segmentation fault) when you later try to modify it.

Note: On your comment about not having to define a default constructor for `Q` - you can remove this *provided* you give the 'required' parameter when you declare/instatiate the `q` member in `P`:

```cpp
class P {
public:
    Q q{ nullptr }; // BEWARE: You can NEVER use this object as it stands!
    int x;
//...
```